# Eclipse XML Formatter broken

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatting

When I want to format my pom.xml the following happens:

From

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

To

```
        <dependency>

            <groupId>
junit
            </groupId>

            <artifactId>
junit
            </artifactId>

            <version>
4.10
            </version>

            <scope>
test
            </scope>
        </dependency>
```

I've tried to restore default settings wherever the XML Editor of Eclipse is involved, although I haven't changed anything knowingly. Any idea where to set this straight?

Comment: Right-click on the file and check its Open With menu.  Are you actually opening it with the XML Editor?

Comment: @nitind You have it right, it was opened with *Android Common XML Editor* changing it back to *XML Editor* fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Window > Preferences* then select from the left navigation *General > Editors > File Association*, choose the file type *.xml* and in the window below select the XML editor and click on *Default*.

[image: File Association Preference Screenshot]